# Bootstrap - Container Width Vs Available Screen Width

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, photoshop

I am a designer and trying to produce output for developers using Bootstrap.

Trying to wrap my head around the difference between the Device Size and the Container size.

For a fixed container - The recommended Large size is 992 px and the Container is 960 px.

Should I design for the whole 992 px ? or 
Should only place designs within the container size - 960px? 
Can the container size be changed to 992 px in a fixed layout ?

Thanks!

Comment: Refer to this link. It might help.
[Link](https://scotch.io/tutorials/default-sizes-for-twitter-bootstraps-media-queries)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like your website will be centered on the page.

If you're happy with the container sizes that Bootstrap uses by default, I would design for them and keep your designs within 960px (for large screens). The extra space on the sides acts as a bugger so that your website is not pressed against the side of the screen, which can cause your designs to appear scrunched and cluttered.

Be aware that Bootstrap isn't designed to be your only style guide. Every project has different needs, and if your project would benefit from different container sizes, you are more than welcome to override those styles for your purposes. They include their source code in SASS for that very reason, and you can always override the styles in your own stylesheet after the fact.

As for designing your UI, I'm not sure what your UI elements look like, but if you're designing for a responsive medium, be sure to design them knowing that your UI will scale. Do your best to design elements that don't rely on a fixed width; let your elements flow and wrap within your components.